# close() the cursor and DB when use the sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

In my application I use the `sqlite Database`,When I run the application Logcat display me

```
close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.MAT.CanadaImmigrationApp/databases/CanadaianImmigrationApp' 
E/Database(13822): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

I search on google and I found

```
db.close();  // to close your Database,
cur.close();     //to close your cursor
```

But I don't get the idea where I add this code?

**DbHelper.class**

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database attributes

public static final String DB_NAME = "DB_NAME";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_QUESTIONS = "Questions_Answers";
public static final String COLUMN_CHAPTERS = "Chapters";
public static final String COLUMN_QUESTIONS = "Question";
public static final String COLUMN_CORRECT_ANSWER = "Correct_Answer";
public static final String COLUMN_OPT1 = "Answer1";
public static final String COLUMN_OPT2 = "Answer2";
public static final String COLUMN_OPT3 = "Answer3";

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    String createTable = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_QUESTIONS + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                                                            + COLUMN_CHAPTERS + " text not null, "
                                                            + COLUMN_QUESTIONS + " text not null, "
                                                            + COLUMN_CORRECT_ANSWER + " text not null, "
                                                            + COLUMN_OPT1 + " text not null, "
                                                            + COLUMN_OPT2 + " text not null, "
                                                            + COLUMN_OPT3 + " text not null);";

    // Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_QUESTIONS);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

**Db_Adapter.class**

```
 public class Db_Adapter  {

public static final String TABLE_QUESTIONS = "Questions_Answers";
public static final String COLUMN_CHAPTERS = "Chapters";
public static final String COLUMN_QUESTIONS = "Question";
public static final String COLUMN_CORRECT_ANSWER = "Correct_Answer";
public static final String COLUMN_OPT1 = "Answer1";
public static final String COLUMN_OPT2 = "Answer2";
public static final String COLUMN_OPT3 = "Answer3";


public static  SQLiteDatabase databasesql;
private  DbHelper Android_OpenDb_Helper;
private   Context mycontext;

public static List<String> question_Set;
public static List<String> Answers_Set;
public static List<String> Option1;
public static List<String> Option2;
public static List<String> Option3;


public Db_Adapter( Context context)
{
    this.mycontext =context;
}
public void close() {
    Android_OpenDb_Helper.close();
  }

public DbHelper createDatabase()
{
    Android_OpenDb_Helper = new DbHelper(mycontext);
    databasesql = Android_OpenDb_Helper.getWritableDatabase();
    return Android_OpenDb_Helper;

} 

public long addToDB(String chapters, String question,
        String correctAnswer, String answer1, String answer2, String answer3)
{
    return databasesql.insert(TABLE_QUESTIONS,null, createContentValues(chapters,question,correctAnswer,answer1,answer2,answer3));
} 

  private ContentValues createContentValues(String chapters, String question,
        String correctAnswer, String answer1, String answer2, String answer3)
{
    ContentValues myContentVal =  new ContentValues();
    myContentVal.put(COLUMN_CHAPTERS, chapters);
    myContentVal.put(COLUMN_QUESTIONS, question);
    myContentVal.put(COLUMN_CORRECT_ANSWER, correctAnswer);
    myContentVal.put(COLUMN_OPT1, answer1);
    myContentVal.put(COLUMN_OPT2, answer2);
    myContentVal.put(COLUMN_OPT3, answer3);


    return myContentVal;
} 

public Cursor readData()
{
    return databasesql.query(TABLE_QUESTIONS, new String[]{COLUMN_CHAPTERS,COLUMN_QUESTIONS,COLUMN_CORRECT_ANSWER,COLUMN_OPT1,COLUMN_OPT2,COLUMN_OPT3}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public Cursor getQuestion()
{
    return databasesql.query(TABLE_QUESTIONS, new String[]{COLUMN_QUESTIONS}, null, null, null, null, null); 
}

public Cursor getQuizQuestions(int numQ)
{
    return databasesql.rawQuery(
            "select * from "+ TABLE_QUESTIONS +" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT "
                    + numQ, null);
}

public List<String> getQuestions(String difficulty) {

    question_Set = new ArrayList<String>();
    Answers_Set = new ArrayList<String>();

    Option1= new ArrayList<String>();
    Option2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Option3 = new ArrayList<String>();



    Cursor c = databasesql.rawQuery(
            "select * from "+TABLE_QUESTIONS+" where CHAPTERS = ?",
            new String[] { difficulty });

    while (c.moveToNext()) {

        question_Set.add(c.getString(2).trim());
        Answers_Set.add(c.getString(3).trim());
        Option1.add(c.getString(4).trim());
        Option2.add(c.getString(5).trim());
        Option3.add(c.getString(6).trim());


    }

    return question_Set;
} 

public int DropTable()
{

    return databasesql.delete(TABLE_QUESTIONS, null, null);
} 

}
```

And I am call this methods like:

For get question :

```
Cursor cursor = DB_Adapter.getQuestion();
```

For get insert :

```
DB_Adapter.addToDB(Chapters,Question,CorrectAnswer,Answer1,Answer2,Answer3);
```

Please let me know where should I add the **`db.close();`**  and  **`cur.close();`**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this scenario:

When ever you want to access with the database help function or fire any query then use to **open** Database.

After using that function or query, always **close** that database.

e.g:

```
db.open(); // function to open database for the use
db.YOUR_QUERY or ANY_FUNCTION
db.close();
```

Open and close of database is use to open databse in perticular mode like writable/readable and close it.

You can use below function in to databaseHelper class to Open and Close the database.

```
 //---opens the database---
public DBAdapter2 open() throws SQLException 
{
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return this;
}

//---closes the database---    
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}
```

Hope it will help you.

**Updated**

change this:

```
    question_Set.add(c.getString(2).trim());
    Answers_Set.add(c.getString(3).trim());
    Option1.add(c.getString(4).trim());
    Option2.add(c.getString(5).trim());
    Option3.add(c.getString(6).trim());
```

with below:

```
        db.open();
    question_Set.add(c.getString(2).trim());
    db.close();
    db.open();
    Answers_Set.add(c.getString(3).trim());
    db.close();
    db.open();
    Option1.add(c.getString(4).trim());
    db.close();
    db.open();
    Option2.add(c.getString(5).trim());
    db.close();
    db.open();
    Option3.add(c.getString(6).trim());
    db.close();
```

Comment: Thanks,and what about the cursor?

Comment: @android: yes, for cursor you have to use same thing. call db.open() before fetching data by cursor and use db.close(); after completed it.

Comment: I am donig this way.but eclipse give me error on open and close the db

DB_Adapter.addToDB(Chapters, Question, CorrectAnswer,
       Answer1, Answer2, Answer3);
     
     DB_Adapter.close();

Comment: is there any method of `open()` and `close()`?

Comment: Yes, see updated answer for the function to open and close the database.

Comment: I am using `db` as the object of `SQLiteDatabase`.then eclipse give error `The method open() is undefined for the type SQLiteDatabase`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19150/discussion-between-idroid-explorer-and-android)

Comment: please declare the function in that class as i have mention in the answer to open database.

Comment: if you want to open DB, and you're extending SQLiteOpenHelper, use:
context.getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase(), which will open/and make read or writeable

Answer (score 2):

After calling the:-

```
DB_Adapter.addToDB(Chapters,Question,CorrectAnswer,Answer1,Answer2,Answer3); 
**db.close();**
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of closing the `Cursor` and `Database object.`

**First Way** 
Close both the object after using it.(i.e whenever the process get completed that relate to your cursor)

**Second Way**

Add it in `OnStop()` or `onDestroy()`.

In `OnStop()` or `onDestroy()` Check whether the cursor and database object is null. If not then close it.

```
public void onStop(){
 if(db!=null)
   {db.close();}
 if(cur!=null)
  { cur.close();}
}
```

It Should work.

Comment: should i add onStop() method in Db_Adapter class?

Comment: Ok,db is the object of the helper class.but what if i used multiple cursor?

Comment: no you dont want to add `onStop()` in DB_ADAPTER Class. It should be in the calling class of DB_ADAPTER. db and cur is the name of the database  and cursor object.(You can call what ever you want). If you have multiple cursor then you have to close all the cursors.

Answer (score 1):

use this method to create data base

my constructor

```html
public DBClass(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  
  this.context = context;
  
  
  
 
  
 }
```

```html
@Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  
  context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prediction(country1 VARCHAR,Country2 VARCHAR,winner VARCHAR,pool VARCHAR);");
 }
```

then in your database accessing functions use like these

```html
public void databaseInsertOperations(String c1, String c2, String c3) {
  db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(DBClass.COUNTRY_1, c1);
  cv.put(DBClass.COUNTRY_2, c2);
  cv.put(DBClass.WINNER, c3);
  db.insert(DBClass.TABLE, null, cv);
  db.close();
 }

 public ArrayList<String> databaseRetriveOperation() {

 
  db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  
  ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();

cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from prediction", null);

  if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
   System.out.println("Error No records found");

  } else {

   while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    buffer.add(cursor.getString(0) + "/" + cursor.getString(1)
      + "/" + cursor.getString(2));
   }
   
  }
  
  db.close();  cursor.close();
  return buffer;

 }
```

worked out for me when i got this error