# My android database application not working in android 2.x

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an application that runs smoothly in android 4.x but not in android 2.x.
What I'm trying to do is to get some information from a web service and store in the database.
what should I do?
This is the code that produce error:

```
public String CallMethod(String methodName,ArrayList<ServiceParam> paramList) {
        String result = "default";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();

        for(int i=0;i<paramList.size();i++){
            ServiceParam serviceParam;
            serviceParam = paramList.get(i);
            pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName(serviceParam.name);
            pi.setValue(serviceParam.value);
            pi.setType(serviceParam.type);
            request.addProperty(pi);
        }

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(namespace+methodName, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            result= response.toString();
            output = result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Ehsan", e.getMessage());
            Log.d("Ehsan", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

the line that produces the error is this:

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
```

this is my log cat:

```
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820): Releasing statement in a finalizer. Please ensure that you explicitly call close() on your cursor: SELECT * FROM settings WHERE name='PersonId'
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:62)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at ClassLibrary.DbHelper.select(DbHelper.java:105)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at com.example.shareholders.entities.Settings.select(Settings.java:93)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at com.example.shareholders.entities.Settings.getValue(Settings.java:56)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at com.example.shareholders.Login.onCreate(Login.java:24)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-26 11:26:02.666: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12820):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.shareholders/databases/shareholders.db' 
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:844)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:540)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at ClassLibrary.DbHelper.select(DbHelper.java:99)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at com.example.shareholders.entities.Settings.select(Settings.java:93)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at com.example.shareholders.entities.Settings.getValue(Settings.java:56)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at com.example.shareholders.Login.onCreate(Login.java:24)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-26 11:26:02.736: E/Database(12820):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: after proceed with `settings` table cursor finally  close your cursor

Comment: update method have nothing to do with cursor!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249129/close-the-cursor-and-db-when-use-the-sqlite-database check this

Comment: Question updated. please help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

`DbHelper db = new DbHelper(context);`
you have to close it.

```
 public int update(String name, String value) {
    DbHelper db = new DbHelper(context);
    try {
        db.openDataBase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("value", value);
        db.update("settings", cv, "name='" + name + "'");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        xLog.error(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        db.closeDataBase();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

DbHelper Class INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest file

```
 private void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    private void closeDataBase() {
        if (databaseHelper != null) {
            databaseHelper.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've find that the problem is for calling web service. question updated.